# Join query that returns position?

Tags: c#, linq, csv

I'll start by saying I'm fairly new to `C#`. 
I have already read Rob Miles book and loved it, trying to work on some practical problems now. 
I'm have a C# project that involves only CSV's and I'm trying to get information pertaining to `matches between strings (serial numbers)` contained in both.

So I have only two types of `CSV files`. The first is a `daily_log (lets say 100 lines)` of everything that is produced. It contains two "columns" `(timestamp and serial)`. The second type of CSV, random_sample, has only one line and it is a `serial` of the exact same format in the daily log.

What I'm trying to do is match the serial from random samples to the daily log file and determine the amount of parts produced between the last serial match of random sample and daily log. I will point out that not every random_sample is always found on daily_log (might be an old sample).

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<string> serials = new List<string>();
    //add stuff to serial from daily_log

    List<string> samples = new List<string>();
    //add stuff to samples from random_samples

    //This is my very crude way of doing it
    List<string> matches = serials.Intersect(samples).ToList();
    string LastMatch = matches[matches.Count()-1];
    Console.WriteLine(result.PartsSinceCheck(LastMatch, serials));
}

private int PartsSinceCheck(string LastMatch, List<string> serials)
{
    int index = (serials.Count() - 1) - serials.FindIndex(s => String.Equals(s, LastMatch, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
    return index;
}
```

Comment: Please post some code to show what you have tried and where you need help, that will help in quickly gathering the relevant points

Comment: My apologies, I have updated the question to include where I am at with the code.